# Killing slept processes in MySQL 5 through an ASP.NET app

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I'm currently working on a legacy ASP.NET 2.0 web application using a MySQL 5 database.
At user login a list of all slept processes are retrieved and killed off.

Why is this task performed in the application (connection leak?)? I would have assumed connection pooling would have taken care of this, but I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to say for sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A week later after a more thorough review it turns out a single connection to the database was not closing correctly and a previous developer selected the nuclear option to fix it.